# Passing sqlContext as an implicit parameter in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a function in a Scala object which has the following signature

```
def f(v1:Int)(implicit sqlContext: SQLContext)
```

when I try to call this function from spark-shell I call it like

```
f(1)
```

and I expect the existing sqlContext gets passed to it implicitly but it doesn't. How can I make it to work so the sqlContext get passed to this function automatically?

--------------update-------------------

I tried to import sqlContext.implicits._ in the spark-shell before calling my function but it didn't help

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you figure it out in the end?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add a `SQLContext` implicitly to the same context which you are calling your function:

```
implicit val sqlContext = new SQLContext() // just an example
// and then
f(1)
```

If you are using apacha Spark, you can use this import:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Comment: but it kill the whole purpose. I'm trying to make it invisible to the user, so user call call my function without defining the sqlContext as implicit, otherwise I could pass sqlContext as a normal parameter.

Comment: I try to import that in the spark-shell, but it doesn't help!

Comment: The user must provide the context in a way or another. I was assuming you are using Spark, are you?

Comment: Anyway, you can define the `SQLContext` somewhere else and your user just need to import your code instead of define it themselves.

Comment: I edited my question, could you have a look? actually importing the sqlContext.implicits._ didn;t help.

Comment: You can create a `SQLContext` from your existing `SparkContext` as well: `implicit val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)`

Comment: You need to define somewhere, if you are writing helper class, pass the context as a constructor argument implicitly